Efficient Triple Numerical Integral Computation with Variable Limit Functions
I have a triple integral expression where the limits of integration depend on other integral parameters. Here is the functions where $0<p<1$:
funUVtest[p_, u_, v_] := 
  1/(u v ) Exp[-(
      0.5/(1 - p^2)) ((2 Log[u] - 1)^2 + (2 Log[v] - 1)^2 - 
       2 p (2 Log[u] - 1) (2 Log[v] - 1))];
funZtest[z_] := Exp[-0.5 (z - 1)^2];
IntTest[p_, t_] := 
  NIntegrate[
   funUVtest[p, u, v] funZtest[z], {z, 0, \[Infinity]}, {v, 1/Sqrt[
    t], \[Infinity]}, {u, (z v)/(Sqrt[t] v - 1), \[Infinity]}];

I am trying to plot but I could not get output
Plot[IntTest[0.6, t], {t, 0, 100}]

It seems very slow for small t like IntTest[0.6, 0.01].
Is there a way to improve the efficiency of this calculation in Mathematica?
